# Make hidden div visible when dv is called from url

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a one page website in which i have multiple div in display:none;

I know how to make them visible and hidden on click but I want to show or hide div when some one change the URL

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var tabId = location.hash; // will look something like "#h-02"

 if(tabId){
   $(tabId).show(); // this will fired only when url get hash
   $(tabId).siblings().hide(); // this will show only targeted tab 
                               // others get hidden
 }
```

This code work on when called from outside and page reloads but not works without reload

for example: index.html#about

if i change change about with contact and enter i will not change unless i refresh my page

can someone help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to listen for the `hashchange` event, as the browser doesn't reload when only the hash changes

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).on('hashchange', function() {

        var tabId = location.hash;

        if(tabId){
            $(tabId).show();
            $(tabId).siblings().hide();
        }

    }).trigger('hashchange');

});
```

Comment: thanks that worked. i am new with java script so i did't hashchange trigger

Answer (score 0):

You may not need javascript at all here. You can use `:target` pseudo class (IE9+). Check it out.

CSS:

```
.chapter {
    display: none;
    padding: 10px;
}
.chapter:target {
    display: block;
}
```

So when for example location.hash is `#h-02` then element with such id will be targeted by `.chapter:target` rule.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zo5cvh6u/